# insert into table from query using GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, insert, group-concat

First thanks to all who help with answers I am always on this site looking for help.  Normally I don't have to post because I find the answer but this is a little more complicated than usual.

I have this MySQL query;

```
select username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userid
    ORDER BY username, userid DESC SEPARATOR '  ')
    FROM users
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING count(*) > 1
```

works perfect

but when I try to user it with a INSERT STATMENT;

```
insert into table comb_scept
select username,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userid
    ORDER BY username, userid DESC SEPARATOR '  ')
    FROM users
    GROUP BY username
    HAVING count(*) > 1
```

I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE comb_scept select username, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userid  ORDER BY usernam' at line 1

I have tried create and get similar error.

Thanks for your Help
Roxanne

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table comb_scept
            ^
```

You don't put the word "table" in an INSERT statement.

See docs for the syntax of INSERT here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: Bill thank you, LOL with me it is always some little thing I miss.  Blessings to you!!!!

Comment: @Roxie, great, I'm glad to help. It is customary on Stack Overflow to upvote an answer that is helpful, and click the check-mark on the answer that solved the problem for you.